# How can I make an object's tip position exactly where the IK controller bone is?

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

So I have this robot leg I made. This is the current setup I have[image]

The selected bone is the IK controller bone. When I tried to move the IK bone to the 3D cursor in edit mode I get this.[image]

So as a work around I instead created 2 bones. The upper one has a copy transforms with the lower one as a target.
[image]

This works kinda fine but I wanted to know if there is a way to make it so that the IK bone is always on the lower part of the leg. For example when using my rig ( I moved the controller IK slightly up and to the left) I get this
[image]

What I want is for the controlller IK to always be within the highlighted region, is this possible?

Comment: I think it would work if you just added bones all the way down the leg, terminating at the IK control.

Comment: You should probably clarify your question, It's a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add one more bone from top controller to bottom:

[image]

Add new IK to it with target to bottom controller and chain length 1

[image]

Finally, reparent this part of leg to this bone

[image]